# How can I filter to a single item in an array bing to it via an angular expression in markup?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a single element that I want bound to a single item in an array and ng-repeat doesn't seem applicable.

How can I do something like the following to bind to a single item in an array

```
<p class="bottomline">{{vehicle.Taglines[0].Tagline | $filter:{MarketId:$scope.MarketId}}</p>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Could you try this:

`{{ (vehicle.Taglines | filter: {MarketId: MarketId})[0]["Tagline"] }}`

Note, `filter` *not* `$filter`! And you have missed a bracket after the filter object argument!

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it worked for me, but intead off `[0]["Tagline"]`, I needed a property of the object and I did something similar to the following  `{{(settings.Languages | filter:{CultureId:settings.SelectedLanguage})[0].Tagline }}`

Comment: Excellent answer - saves tons of work over alternate methods.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible but you can always write that logic in the Controller (and avoid putting so much logic in the template)

```
module('yourApp', []).controller(['$scope, $filter', function Controller($scope, $filter){
    $scope.$watch('MarketId', function(marketId) {
        $scope.tagLineFound = $filter('filter')($scope.vehicle.Taglines, marketId)[0];
    });
}]);
```

HTML

```
<p class="bottomline">{{tagLineFound.Tagline}}</p>
```